# JPA "cannot be cast to java.sql.Blob"

Tags: java, hibernate, blob, jpa-2.0, derby

I'm using JPA2 with hibernate 3.6.1. and a Derby database and I used the following annotation for a blob:

```
@Column(length = Integer.MAX_VALUE)
@Lob
long[] bucket;
```

Hibernate creates the correct blob column but if I try to save an entity I get the following exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: [J cannot be cast to java.sql.Blob

why and how can I make this work?

If I annotate it without the @Lob I get a "Varchar for bit data" column which can only contain up to 32m.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to map the property as a byte[], not as long[].

The [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html) says

> @Lob indicates that the property
>   should be persisted in a Blob or a
>   Clob depending on the property type:
>   java.sql.Clob, Character[], char[] and
>   java.lang.String will be persisted in
>   a Clob. java.sql.Blob, Byte[], byte[]
>   and serializable type will be
>   persisted in a Blob.
>
> If the property type implements
>   java.io.Serializable and is not a
>   basic type, and if the property is not
>   annotated with @Lob, then the
>   Hibernate serializable type is used.

If you want to persist the array, you'll need to build a custom user type to transform the data type. You can find an example here http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html#d0e2794

Comment: ok, thanks. Is there any other way to persist a long[] without having to "convert" it to a byte[] or something manually?

Comment: Please check the answer, I've added a link with one example from the documentation.